# Update and remove redundant node tree

Tags: c#, .net

I'm meeting the issue but I sill no have the way how to resolve it

[image]

[image]

When I update tree 1 from tree 2 . My expectation result

[image]

But I actual result like this

[image]

My code

```cs
public class OrgChartViewModel
    {
        public int OrgChartId { get; set; }

        public UserViewModel Current { get; set; }

        public List<OrgChartViewModel> Children { get; set; }

        public string ParentInterfaceId { get; set; }

        public string InterfaceId { get; set; }
    }
```

Short code to create my structure
I included my link to get this code . I cant give code here cause I met message "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." . I cant fixed
[click to view code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1cO793)

Email is identify each node 
What do I need update my code . Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls your method, along with some code that creates the two trees structures?

Comment: If you can't post your code here, try putting a full working example at https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and post a link to it in your question.

Comment: This is a piece of code in my project . If u want to know flow code i will put this . sure i cant compile code  cause it relate to other code . Y can get link again

Comment: I think we are just looking for the smallest fully working example that demonstrates your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example